# How to derive geometric mean

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $(1+r_g)^n = (1+r_1)(1+r_2)$, how should I derive the formula such that $r_g = (r_1r_2)^{1/n}$. I am trying to prove that $r_g = (r_1r_2)^{1/n}$.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right equations? $r_1 = 3$, $r_2 = 0$, $n=2$, $r_g = 1$ makes the equation $(1+r_g)^n = (1+r_1)(1+r_2)$ true, but it's clearly not true that $r_g = 1 = 0 = r_1 r_2$.

Comment: Let r = {$ r\_g$} and R = {$ R\_g$} such that $ R\_g = r\_g + 1$. Then we have $R_g = (R_1R_2)^{1/n}$. That is, such format is possible only if each member of the original sequence is increased by 1.

Answer (score 0):

If 1+$r_1, $(1+r_g) and 1+$r_2 are in geometric progression, as your first equation indicates, then $r_1, $r_g and $r_2 also being in G.P is not possible (for all such numbers), AFAIK. There might be numbers satisfying that condition, but it cannot be a general truth that can be proved.